# Unable to retrieve keyvault secret with user assigned managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

This is a cross post from [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5121).
I have a console app using "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.2.0-preview" and "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.2".

I have a user assigned managed identity on my Windows 2019 VM.

The managed identity has been given the contributor role assignment on my keyvault and read to the resource group it lives in.

I am using a user assigned managed identity as the intention is to run a similar app in a kubernetes pod (with aad-pod identity). I have a connection string environment variable set as AzureServicesAuthConnectionString RunAs=App;<clientId of my user assigned MI>;TenantId=<tenantId>

When I try to connect to the keyvault to retrieve a secret I get a Forbidden exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden') --->
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation
>   returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2
>   customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync(IKeyVaultClient
>   operations, String secretIdentifier, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at msiauth.AzureStuff.Run() in
>   C:\Users\aiadmin\src\azure\msiauth\tests.cs:line 50
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() at msiauth.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in C:\Users\aiadmin\src\azure\msiauth\Program.cs:line 10

When I try to create a Resource Group using "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" Version="2.0.0-preview" it works fine so the user assigned MI works for that.

I tried the exact same keyvault code but with a system assigned managed identity and it worked correctly so permissions are fine and the code works.

Has anybody been able to do this in .net core?

Answer (score 2):

Reading or writing secrets from or to the KeyVault is an operation on the Key Vault itself and is allowed (or not) based on the Access Policies set.

The contributor role you are referring belongs to the Azure Resource Manager RBAC system and allows to manage the KeyVault (f.e. assign access policies).

Most likely the identity that does work has both an RBAC assignment and an access policy. The one that doesn't work will need an access policy (and doesn't need an RBAC assignment)

For more on access policies see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#authorize

Comment: Many services in Azure have their own Access Control for things e.g. Key Vault, Data Lake, SQL DB :)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I have assigned access policies too.

Comment: @bunzab, were you able to figure it out? I am having the same issue. Access policy is set but still getting Forbidden for user assigned msi

Comment: currently its not solved. fk